# Windows installation logs remotely

Tags: winapi, logging, windows-server-2012-r2, setup-deployment

I'm installing the Windows Server 2012 R2 through PXE. Is it possible to collect the Windows setup activity logs remotely. Like syslog in linux which collects an installation status lively.

I tried to run syslogen.exe syslogd.exe from the winpe environment but shows the error message as "The subsystem needed to support the image type is not present"

or else

Is there any API is available to access the setup log files?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a number of subsystems to the WinPE image - it's very likely that one or more are required to run the program you're using (although it's hard to say what particular subsystems you need).

There's a whole dance to updating WinPE. You have to mount it (using DISM) and then you can add everything you need. There are special subcommands for adding packages (the subsystems)...and you can also add required files directly to the mounted image if/when you have special programs to add.

The idea is, the WinPE is slim by default (important for PXE). For a list of subsystems you can add, have a look [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference)